# Recommendation based on correlation

Tags: correlation

everyone! My question is very basic.

If we find a statistical correlation between grade-point averages and test scores after taking an online short course, what kind of recommendation for a policy can we give based on this?

Can we recommend that the school develops different courses to suit students with different grade-point averages so as to help them get better test scores?

Thank you very much.

[Edited]

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to know what caused the effect when all you have is a correlation. How do you know you don't need different courses for people with different test scores to help them get better grade-point averages?